# how to use sendkeys to copy text from outside application

Tags: .net, vb.net, vbscript, sendkeys

I have a specific application (someprogram.exe) i wish to use the sendkeys command to perform CTRL + C from the application i'm bulding in vb.net. I don't need to bring the data into my app, just copy it to the windows clipboard.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, Could you please provide more info on "someprogram.exe"? Basically what type of application is it? (winform, console, etc) What type of Control are you trying to get the data from? (Textbox, console window, etc) What type of data is it that you are trying to get into the Clipboard? (image, text, etc) After you specify these question maybe someone else or I will be able to help a little more.

Comment: the application i believe is written in .NET (c#). Im trying to get a textbox (preferably selection) copied to the clipboard (text).

Answer (score 0):

i would Recommand to send the message GETTEXT to handle of that control (use FindWindow api maybe to get the handle) and then set it yourself to the clipboard, to avoid copying wrong data or only the selected part of it.

Comment: THis sounds like exactly what i want to do. The window name on the application will change depending on what user is logged in (multi user) sort of a "Application - welcome joe" so I can't really hard code the name of the open window i wish to grab the text from.

Comment: @gfuller40 I think this is the only way to do it though, you will have to find the partial text (the "Application -" part) and maybe ask the user of this is the window you are looking for.

Comment: @gfuller40 is you know the application file name (the .exe) you can search for the process, and than find it's main window. (the process class will take care of it, the property process.mainmodule.filename and process.mainwindowhandle)

Comment: Was this the appropriate answer? if so please set it as accepted